# Select value in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, return-value, google-tag-manager

I am new here. I want to get 'value' from string. In the code below, get the numbers after the colon: return 59.85

```
document.querySelector("div.column1.container > div.column1.content > script")

gtag('event', 'conversion', {
'send_to': 'AW-615429024/N2wOCNOMveYBEKDnuqUC',
'value': 59.85,
'currency': 'TRY',
'transaction_id': '08112020160736-MWO'
});
```

**After colon** but **before the comma**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e3l8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9p85.png)

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do in more detail? What do you mean by "getting 'value' from String"?

Comment: provide your code in text

Comment: be more clear but use this maybe it works :  inputstring.match(/(?<='value'( )*:( )*)[^,]*/gm)[0]

Comment: provide gtag please . in gtag you can use thirdArgument.value to access value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using `gtag.js`. The third argument is the additional configuration options but I'm not sure why you are asking for the value since you are the one making the object for it.

Anyway to access any object's keys you need to assign it to a variable like this:

```
let obj = {
'send_to': 'AW-615429024/N2wOCNOMveYBEKDnuqUC',
'value': 59.85,
'currency': 'TRY',
'transaction_id': '08112020160736-MWO'
}
```

To access the key called `value`, just use `obj.value` . The following line should print the value in console.

```
console.log(obj.value)
```

Alternatively, you can use the following to access the 'value' key:

```
({
'send_to': 'AW-615429024/N2wOCNOMveYBEKDnuqUC',
'value': 59.85,
'currency': 'TRY',
'transaction_id': '08112020160736-MWO'
}).value
```

Comment: This is not my site. I want to get the total amount from customers.
I'm learning javascript so I didn't know this method. Thank You very much :)